# How to select a DOM node with two data attributes for updating

Tags: jquery

I have the following HTML:

```
<div class='tag-enabled' data-global-id='1635' data-tag-id='8'>hello</div>
<div class='tag-enabled' data-global-id='1635' data-tag-id='9'>hello</div>
<div class='tag-enabled' data-global-id='1635' data-tag-id='10'>hello</div>
```

I'd like to select `data-global-id=1635` and `data-tag-id=8` in jQuery. How would I do this?

Comment: not a duplicate of that question

Comment: Really? Why? How is yours any different?

Comment: multiple selectors - not trying to be argumentative. I'm not a jQuery expert. appreciate you read question but I didn't even get that answer when I googled the title.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use two [attribute selectors](http://api.jquery.com/attribute-equals-selector/):

```
$("[data-global-id='1635'][data-tag-id='8']")
```

[Updated fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/5QeUQ/)

Comment: thx Adrift - that works well, have to wait a few minutes